# Splunk HTTP collection ignores props.conf file

Tags: splunk

I'm uploading historical data to Splunk and need default Splunk's `_time` values to be replaced with values from my custom `START_TIME` key
I know that it can be done with help of `props.conf` file but it works only with data uploaded from directory, not via HTTP collection
Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can force a given field in the JSON data coming into the HEC to be the timestamp

If you do not, `_time` will populate with the timestamp of when it is received by Splunk

This line in `props.conf` will set `_time` to index/received time:

```
DATETIME_CONFIG = CURRENT
```

Check out the [`props.conf`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Admin/Propsconf) docs for more examples

Answer (score 0):

The exact behavior depends on which HEC endpoint is used.

For the services/collector/event endpoint, the timestamp can be extracted from the envelope, the event, or the URL.  See https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/9.1.1/RESTREF/RESTinput#services.2Fcollector.2Fevent

The services/collector/raw endpoint can get the timestamp from the `time` parameter.  See https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/9.1.1/RESTREF/RESTinput#services.2Fcollector.2Fraw